# Plot multiple line graphs on one graph

Tags: r, matrix, plot, curve, linegraph

I can get a single power curve shown below but I want to create a power analysis graph. I want to change my delta value (to .6, .7, and .8) and plot those 3 other lines on that same r curve in a different color. I provided an example of what I kinda want it to look.

```
n_participants <- c(5, 10, 20, 30, 40)

npercluster <- 20

n_tot <- n_participants*npercluster

icc <- 0.6  # assumption

deff <- 1 + icc*(npercluster - 1)

ess <- n_tot / deff

mydelt <- 0.5  

mypowers <- power.t.test(n=ess, delta=mydelt)$power

plot(n_participants, mypowers, type='l', 
     main=paste('Power based on', npercluster, 'volumes per participants'), 
     xlab='Number of participants', ylim=c( 0, 1), 
     ylab='Power')
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: see `?matplot`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are planning to use R a lot I would recommend investing in learning  `ggplot2`.  Base R plotting solutions get very limited very quickly.

To solve your problem I would make a data frame with every combination of effect size and sample size.

```
dat <- expand.grid(mydelt=c(0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8), ess=n_tot / deff)
```

Then add a column for the power:

```
dat$mypowers = power.t.test(n=dat$ess, delta=dat$mydelt)$power
```

Then I can use `ggplot` to easily make a nice graph of the power curves:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dat, aes(x=ess, y=mypowers, color=factor(mydelt))) + geom_point() + geom_line()
```

[image]

You can easily change the overall graph look and add appropriate labels:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x=ess, y=mypowers, color=factor(mydelt))) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_line() + 
  theme_bw() + 
  labs(x="Effective sample size", y="Power", color="Effect size" )
```

[image]

In response to the comment.. there was a mistake in the code above in that I plotted the effective total sample size on the `x` axis not the sample size per cluster.  So instead we should make sure we have `n_participants` in the dataset for plotting, then calculate the powers and plot:

So the whole script is now:

```
n_participants <- 5:40
npercluster <- 20
icc <- 0.6  # assumption
deff <- 1 + icc*(npercluster - 1)

dat <- expand.grid(mydelt=c(0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8), npart=n_participants)
dat$n_tot <- dat$npart*npercluster
dat$ess <- dat$n_tot / deff
dat$mypowers <- power.t.test(n=dat$ess, delta=dat$mydelt)$power

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dat, aes(x=npart, y=mypowers, color=factor(mydelt))) + 
  geom_line()+
  theme_bw() + 
  labs(x="Number of participants", y="Power", color="Effect size" )
```

Which gives this graph:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! That is so helpful. I had two smaller questions: How would I add a limit of 40 to stop the x-bar from going beyond a 40 sample size? Also, how would I remove the points and create smooth curve?

Comment: I've updated the answer.  Also I noticed I made a mistake in my first answer, I plotted the effective sample size on the x axis not the number of participants.  I've fixed that now, but still check I've got the numbers right.

Answer (score 0):

You may put the logic in a function `f`, `sapply` over desired `deltas` and - as also suggested in comments - use `matplot` without having to bother with any new packages.

```
f <- \(mydelt=.5, n_participants=c(5, 10, 20, 30, 40), npercluster=20, icc=.6) {
  n_tot <- n_participants*npercluster
  deff <- 1 + icc*(npercluster - 1)
  ess <- n_tot/deff
  power.t.test(n=ess, delta=mydelt)$power
}

deltas <- seq(.5, .8, .1)

res <- t(sapply(deltas, f))

matplot(res, type='l', main=paste('Power based on 20 volumes per participants'), 
        xlab='Number of participants', 
        ylab='Power')

legend('topleft', legend=deltas, col=seq_along(deltas), lty=seq_along(deltas), 
       title='delta', cex=.8)
```

[image]

It's also possible pipe it directly into `matplot`:

```
t(sapply(deltas, f)) |> 
  matplot(res, ...)
```

See `?matplot` for easy customizing of colors, linetypes etc.

**Note:** R >= 4.1 used.